# e12-table - replace resistors

Tags: resistors, resistance

Is this the table of 12 resistor series?

10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82

http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/E12_%28resistorserie%29

And if I have a resistor of let say 1670 ohm - how do I use this table to find new resistors that can replace 1670?

very greatful for help

*(this is an assignment in c-programming and I don know much about this stuff)*

Comment: If you want to replace a resistor, you go to the supplier and buy the appropriate resistor.  If this is an assignment, then what have you figured out (or attempted) so far?

Comment: @NickAlexeev - assignment in programming - not in electronics. I have googled all day and cannot find much about e12. When I know how this works I can implement this in a program.

Comment: Here's the article explaining E12 and other [preferred number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number) series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in various part series have been decided by approximately evenly dividing a decade exponentially:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 12):
...   print 10**(1+(i/12.))
... 
10.0
12.1152765863
14.6779926762
17.7827941004
21.5443469003
26.1015721568
31.6227766017
38.3118684956
46.4158883361
56.234132519
68.1292069058
82.5404185268
```

It is therefore feasible to take the log10 of a value, examine the fractional component, and drop it into one of the bins.

Comment: ok - so for instance - if I have 3 resistances that is serial - R1 30 ohms, R2 60 ohms R3 100 ohm - I take the sum which is 190. Then I use this table - find those values that best matches 190. correct?

Comment: @java its "in series" and yes, that would be the usual approach.

Comment: @Golaž - ok but how do I use the table if the connections is paralell? then its the inverse, that is 1/SUM(Rn) ... isnt it?

Comment: You will always end up with a single final resistance. Use that resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Odd value resistors can be make one up from 2 or more in parallel or series. Eg, 2 x 3300 ohm resistors in parallel will give you 1650 ohm. Then just add 20 ohms in series.

Comment: 1200 + 470 = 1670, saves you a resistor ;o)